# How to configure quartz to execute the jobs in a specific server

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have a web application which uses QUARTZ to schedule and execute jobs. The production setup is as following: two servers behind a load balancer, QUARTZ is configured to be clustered and both servers can schedule and execute jobs. Now we need to add a third server that will be dedicated to jobs execution. We will call it "Jobs Server". The two front servers will not execute any jobs. But we need them to be able to Schedule jobs (from the application UI). 
What is the correct configuration for QUARTZ at each server to enable the previous setup? Do we need to do any custom code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not (auto-)start Quartz schedulers on AS1 (Application Sever 1) and AS2 and start it only on JS (Jobs Server). Then use one of the Quartz remote APIs (JMX or RMI) to schedule/manage your jobs remotely on JS.

Alternatively, you can (auto-)start Quartz schedulers on AS1 and AS2, but pause them immediately after they start up, e.g. from the [schedulerStarted](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/SchedulerListener.html#schedulerStarted()) callback method.

To be on the safe side that AS1 and AS2 will not execute any jobs between they are started and paused, you should also set their Quartz scheduler's worker thread pool size to 0.